# Fill circle with other circles completely in D3 circle pack

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, circle-pack

Good ...

I am using this example from the following url (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535
):

[image]

My problem is that when inserting many circles, the main circle is not filled correctly as a kind of exaltation is created, my boss wants princial fills the circle.

I leave the code and a screenshot!

```
var margin = 10,
    outerDiameter = 1000,
    innerDiameter = outerDiameter - margin - margin;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, innerDiameter]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, innerDiameter]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .padding(0.5)
    .size([innerDiameter, innerDiameter])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })

var svg = d3.select("#chart4").append("svg")
    .attr("width", outerDiameter)
    .attr("height", outerDiameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");



    nodes = pack.nodes(testHeatMap);

    svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      //.attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d,i){

          if(d.color)
              return d.color
              else if(d.children[0].color)
                  return d.children[0].color
                  else return d.children[0].children[i].color


      })
      .style("fill-opacity", "0.25")
      .style("stroke", function (){ return "rgb(31, 119, 180)"})
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", outerDiameter + "px");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. What does it currently look like and what do you want it to look like?